# NoSuchWindowError: Browsing context has been discarded with GeckoDriver Firefox and Protractor(Selenium)

Tags: angularjs, linux, selenium, protractor, geckodriver

I'm trying to run a simple test script using protractor.

Environment:

```
Node Version: v9.8.0
Protractor Version: 5.4.1
Angular Version: 1.x
Browser(s): Mozilla Firefox 60.1.0
Operating System and Version: HELiOS release 6.10
```

Here's my protractor config file.

```
exports.config = {
  specs: ['todo-spec.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    marionette : true
  }
};
```

This is my test script (todo-spec.js)

```
describe('application homepage', function() {
  it('should open homepage', function() {
    console.log("Opening localhost app");
    browser.get('http://localhost:8080/app/');
    browser.sleep(20000); // just to check if application loaded or not
  });
});
```

This is my **node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/** directory looks like:

[image]

When I run my test using `/path/to/protractor conf.js`, I'm getting below mentioned error.

```
[16:51:03] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:51:03] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[16:51:04] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://<ip-address>:45089/wd/hub
Started
Opening localhost
F

Failures:
1) application homepage should open homepage
  Message:
    Failed: Browsing context has been discarded
    Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
    System info: host: 'HOSTNAME', ip: 'ip_address', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
  Stack:
    NoSuchWindowError: Browsing context has been discarded
    Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
    System info: host: 'HOSTNAME', ip: 'ip_address', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/export/home/test/protractor_test_2/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
        at parseHttpResponse (/export/home/test/protractor_test_2/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
        at doSend.then.response (/export/home/test/protractor_test_2/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
        at <anonymous>
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)
    From: Task: Protractor.get(http://localhost:8080/app/) - reset url
        at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (/export/home/test/protractor_test_2/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:807:17)
        at ProtractorBrowser.executeScriptWithDescription (/export/home/test/protractor_test_2/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:404:28)
        at driver.controlFlow.execute.then.then.then (/export/home/test/protractor_test_2/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:679:25)
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/export/home/test/protractor_test_2/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1376:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/export/home/test/protractor_test_2/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/export/home/test/protractor_test_2/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
        at asyncRun (/export/home/test/protractor_test_2/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2927:27)
        at /export/home/test/protractor_test_2/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
        at <anonymous>
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)
    From: Task: Run it("should open homepage") in control flow
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/export/home/test/protractor_test_2/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:19)
    From asynchronous test:
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/export/home/test/protractor_test_2/todo-spec.js:2:3)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/export/home/test/protractor_test_2/todo-spec.js:1:63)
        at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 0.159 seconds

[16:51:06] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[16:51:06] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[16:51:06] I/launcher - firefox #01 failed 1 test(s)
[16:51:06] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[16:51:06] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);` Which help protractor to wait for all the angular elements to get loaded.

Comment: Added this line below browser.get(URL); Still facing same issue.

Comment: Confirm whether you get the same when trying to run in chrome

Comment: Hi Madhan, In our embedded restricted environment, unfortunately, installing chrome is not a possibility :-|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix this issue with below configuration.

```
- Protractor: v5.4.1 
- Selenium JAR driver: selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar 
- geckodriver:geckodriver-v0.20.0-linux64
```

Also we need to give path of geckodrvier in protractor conf file.

```
geckoDriver: 'node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.20.0'
```

By default webdriver-manager will download latest version of geckodriver which is 0.24.0. But the needed geckdriver is v0.20.0, so I downloaded this manually and placed it inside node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/ directory.

Hope this helps to people facing similar issue.

Answer (score 7):

This error message...

```
Failed: Browsing context has been discarded
```

...implies that the communication between **GeckoDriver** and **Marionette** was broken.

Some more information regarding the *GeckoDriver* binary version would have given us some clues about whats wrong happening. However this issue can happen due to multiple factors as follows:

- As per [Hang when navigation request removes the current browsing context](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/918) if you have used `driver.navigate().back();` when *Selenium's* focus was within an `<iframe>` this error is observed.
- As per [Crash during command execution results in "Internal Server Error: Failed to decode response from marionette"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1401131) this issue can also occur due to **ctypes checks for NULL pointer derefs**.

  - You can find the *Selenium testcase* [here](https://bug1401131.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=8909692). Perhaps instead of panicking, it would have been better to handle this more gracefully by clearing any state and returning geckodriver to accept new connections again.
- As per [Failed to decode response from marionette - Error to open Webdriver using python](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/690) this issue can also occur if you are not using the complient version of the binaries.

### This usecase

The root cause of this issue seems to be **MemoryUsage**. As per [Intermittent awsy\test_memory_usage.py TestMemoryUsage.test_open_tabs | NoSuchWindowException: Browsing context has been discarded](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1431542) which is *intermittent* in nature. This issue was once marked as **RESOLVED** then again **REOPENED**.

As @Madhan mentioned while working with [AngularJS](https://angular.io/) applications and *Protractor* always include:

```
waitForAngularEnabled(true);
```

Finally, as per best practices while working with *GeckoDriver*, *Selenium* and *Firefox Browser* follow the below compatibility chart:

### [Supported platforms](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html)

[image: supported_platforms_geckodriver_24]

Comment: Thank you Debanjan for detailed explanation on all possible root causes. Since my usecase is simple (todo-spec.js), do you think any workaround exists for this? For me, I don't have luxury to downgrade/upgrade Firefox version in our restricted embedded environment, but I can certainly play around with different versions of protractor/selenium/gecko.

Comment: @AakashRayate In that case you have to adjust (upgrade/downgrade) both the _Selenium_ and _GeckoDriver_ version as per the existing _Firefox_ version.