# Browsing context has been discarded (NoSuchWindowError)

Tags: python, ruby, selenium, geckodriver

I am using a simple script to test a website.
Here is my code(I tried similar code for python too):

```
require 'watir'
require 'headless'
headless = Headless.new
headless.start
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto 'https://www.google.com'
search_text = "Watir"
browser.text_field(name: "q").set search_text
browser.button(name: "btnK").click # "btnG" is the name of the Search button
```

Environment:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Firefox: 94.0
Geckodriver: 0.30
Ruby: ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

Getting following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    21: from TWikiUpdate.rb:11:in `<main>'
    20: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/watir-7.1.0/lib/watir/navigation.rb:16:in `goto'
    19: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:32:in `to'
    18: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:93:in `get'
    17: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:588:in `execute'
    16: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
    15: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/watir-7.1.0/lib/watir/http_client.rb:6:in `request'
    14: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:109:in `request'
    13: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:83:in `create_response'
    12: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:83:in `new'
    11: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:35:in `initialize'
    10: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:56:in `assert_ok'
     9: from _onJSONObjectReady/<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/transport.js:500:20
     8: from onPacket@chrome://remote/content/marionette/server.js:253:9
     7: from onPacket/<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/server.js:252:20
     6: from execute@chrome://remote/content/marionette/server.js:279:16
     5: from despatch@chrome://remote/content/marionette/server.js:306:40
     4: from GeckoDriver.prototype.navigateTo@chrome://remote/content/marionette/driver.js:778:34
     3: from assert.open@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Assert.jsm:143:4
     2: from assert.that/<@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Assert.jsm:435:13
     1: from NoSuchWindowError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:415:5
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:181:5: Browsing context has been discarded (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchWindowError)
```

Both ruby and python code are giving same error.

EDIT: This answer ([Protractor(Selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54515173/nosuchwindowerror-browsing-context-has-been-discarded-with-geckodriver-firefox)) does not answer my question. First of all I am using compatible version of selenium/geckodriver/ruby/python. Secondly the mentioned answer does not talk about reason of the error and how to solve it.