# Selenium wait for element_to_be_clickable throws error, manual waiting works

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

In the HTML i have a table where the first column includes a radio button:

[image]

I want to select and click the button with the following code:

```
rdoBtn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "rdoSelection")))
rdoBtn.click()
```

When i run this i get the error:

```
NoSuchWindowException: 'Browsing context has been discarded'
```

However when i go in my debugger and slowly go through this part it works as intented.
Also the `element_to_be_clickable` already worked on other normal buttons before.

Why does it behave this way and how can i fix it?

Comment: Check if this answer helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54530472/7598774

Comment: Im using neither Geckodriver nor Protractor so i dont think so unfortunatly :/

Comment: sounds like a frame or tab/window problem.  Are there any iframes on the page, or multiple tabs/windows open in the browser?  (the driver's stuck in either a frame or window that no longer exists...)  When exactly is the error thrown?  On the click or the next action.. might need to include more code.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.